# Adding items to Listbox in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, listbox, logic

I would like my Listbox widget to be updated upon clicking of a button. However I encountered a logic error. When I click on the button, nothing happens. No errors at all.

```
listOfCompanies: [[1, ''], [2, '-'], [3, '@ASK TRAINING PTE. LTD.'], [4, 'AAIS'], [5, 'Ademco'], [6, 'Anacle']

def populatebox():
            listBox.insert("end", listOfCompanies)

btn = Button(self, text="Update list", command = lambda: populatebox())
btn.pack()
```

Comment: I don't believe that you don't get an error. `listOfCompanies` is a `list` which does not exist inside the function `populatebox()` so when calling it inside that function it returns an error `NameError: name 'listOfCompanies' is not defined`. So you are guaranteed to return an error with the code you provided us.

Comment: read-access to the list is possible even if the list is not defined within populatebox() - so Python is not going to complain about that

Comment: @DonGru The `list` doesn't exist, full stop. She has declared it incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to just insert every `tuple` into the `Listbox` from the `list` as they are without separating out the `tuple` then there are two major changes.

First you cannot declare a list as `list: [1, 2, 3, ...]`, it must be `list = [1, 2, 3, ...]`.

Secondly, you are currently attempting to insert the entire `list` onto one entry in the `Listbox`. You should instead iterate over them, see below for an example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

listBox = Listbox(root)
listBox.pack()

listOfCompanies = [[1, ''], [2, '-'], [3, '@ASK TRAINING PTE. LTD.'], [4, 'AAIS'], [5, 'Ademco'], [6, 'Anacle']]

def populatebox():
    for i in listOfCompanies:
        listBox.insert("end", i)

btn = Button(root, text="Update list", command = lambda: populatebox())
btn.pack()
```

Comment: Actually, I got the list from reading a .csv file however I did not include it in the original post as I thought it would make the post too lengthy and it was irrelevant. 
Either way, I tried placing the code you've suggested and similarly, it gave no output and no error when I clicked on the button.

Comment: If this solution answers your question, please can you mark it as accepted for future users.